# Detect if an element has not be hovered over for 5 seconds

Tags: jquery, events, dom, hover

I have a `hover` event that removes a small button and replaces it with a full menu bar when it's hovered over.

What I would like to do is make is that that if the mouse is not hovered over the menu bar (`this.element`) for 5 seconds (with the timer reset each time a `hover` event occurs on it), the reverse happens.

```
this.button.on('hover', function(e){

    t.admin_bar.show('slide', { 'direction': t.options.position }, 500);
    t.button.hide('slide', { 'direction': t.options.position }, 500);

});
```

---

## Update

With the help of the comments and answers so far provided, I have come up with this. However, even though the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events are working, the `clearTimout()` doesn't seem to be as the admin bar is still being hidden.

```
_create_events : function(){

    var t = this;   // This object

    t.admin_bar = t.element

    /** Capture when the mouse is hovered over the 'Show admin bar' button */
    t.button.on('hover', function(e){

        t._show_admin_bar();
        t._set_timeout();   // Start a new timeout (to hide the admin bar if it's not hovered on)

    });

    /** Capture when the mouse is hovered over the admin bar */
    t.admin_bar.on('mouseenter', function(e){

        clearTimeout(t.timer);  // Clear the existing timeout

    });

    /** Capture when the mouse leaves the admin bar */
    t.admin_bar.on('mouseleave', function(e){

        t._set_timeout();   // Restart the timout

    });

}, // _create_events

_set_timeout : function(){

    var t = this;   // This object

    t.timer = setTimeout(function(){
        t._hide_admin_bar();
    }, 5000);

}, // _timeout

_show_admin_bar : function(){

    this.admin_bar.show('slide', { 'direction': this.options.position }, 500);  // Show the admin bar
    this.button.hide('slide', { 'direction': this.options.position }, 500);     // Hide the 'Show admin bar' button

}, // _show_bar

_hide_admin_bar : function(){

    this.admin_bar.hide('slide', { 'direction': this.options.position }, 500);  // Hide the admin bar
    this.button.show('slide', { 'direction': this.options.position }, 500);     // Show the 'Show admin bar' button

}
```

Comment: Mysteriously disappearing UI elements.  The UI of the future.

Comment: Set a timeout in the hover exit function that does what you want. And have the hover handler function clear the timeout.

Comment: @Barmar - Thanks, `setTimeout()` looks to be the way to go. Now just to suss out how to use it correctly! Thanks.

Comment: Look at my answer below and it will show you how to use it. Its just pseudo code so youll have to add in the hiding and showing but the timeout code is there.

Comment: Can you make a fiddle? The way youre coding all of this is making it harder to follow and I think youre having referencing problems with t.timer.

Comment: Could you try making the timeout just a regular global variable instead of tying it into the `t` object

Comment: I've created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KdStd/) with my current version, but I'm having trouble getting the events to work. I'm not a fiddle expert, so I may be missing something. Also, I've tried with a global `var timer;` and it's still the same. Thanks.

Comment: @DavidGard were your events working before you tried putting it in a fiddle?

Comment: I think i figured it out check out my update.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try something like...

```
var timer;
function hide(){
    //Hide your menu bar
}
function show(){
    //Show your menu bar
}

$("#buttonID").hover(
  function() {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    show();
  }, function() {
    timer = setTimeout(function(){hide()},5000);
  }
);
```

UPDATE:

The problem was with you calling `.on("hover" function...` This is a handler that binds both the mouseenter and mouse leave and is confusing in my opinion. I prefer to either use just mouseenter or the hover() function. So I changed your code to

```
t.button.on('mouseenter', function (e) {
    t._show_admin_bar();
    t._set_timeout(); // Start a new timeout (to hide the admin bar if it's not hovered on)
 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KdStd/1/

Comment: `setTimeout(hide,5000)`

Comment: What you said about `on.('hover', ...` got me thinking. My problem was that when you moved the mouse over the reveal button as it was sliding away, the `timeout` was being started again, leading to some funkyness. I've put a check in now to ensure that the event only fires once, and then is reset when the reveal button is shown again. To do this I use the function `_can_show()`. There may be a more elegant solution, which I'll work on, but this seems to work for now. Updated fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/KdStd/2/

Comment: @DavidGard Looks good to me. Let me know if you need anymore help.